# what is the default weight initialization used in Pytorch embedding layer?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

When we create an embedding layer using the class `torch.nn.Embedding`, how are the weights initialized ? Is uniform, normal or initialization techniques like *He* or *Xavier* used by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Embedding`, by default, the weights are initialization from the Normal distribution. You can check it from the [`reset_parameters()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/sparse.html#Embedding) method:

```
def reset_parameters(self):
        init.normal_(self.weight)
        ...
```